# Can one function have two different return types?

Tags: c++

So today on a test, we had a code, and we had output of the code, and we needed to write the function.

```
std::vector<double> v;
auto z = first(v);
std::cout << z << std::endl;  // OUTPUT: No value!
v.push_back(3.14);
z = first(v);
std::cout << z << std::endl;  // OUTPUT: 3.14
```

Function that we needed to write was `first()`. It takes a `vector` of any type as argument, and it returns the first element of the `vector` (if the `vector` isn't empty).

I did it like this:

```
template <typename T>
std::string first(const std::vector<T>& ve){
    if(ve.empty())
        return "No value!";
    else
        return std::to_string(*(ve.begin()));
}
```

When I asked my teacher how `to_string()` goes, because I didn't know what the name of `to_string()` was, he said that I don't need it because `auto z = first(v)` shouldn't be a string.

How am I supposed to get the output `No value!` if `first()` does not return a string?

Comment: This is too short for a comment or answer, but No.

Comment: What exactly did the test say the function's return value should be if the vector is empty? But already I see that in the case that it's nonempty, you're supposed to return _the first element itself_, not a string representation of the first element.

Comment: Can you return a `NaN` value? (For an empty vector.)

Comment: Well in these casses its just sensible to return something like `NULL` incase the vector is empty! And you could do the check for it where you are calling `first` and print `No value` tthere

Comment: If the `vector` is never supposed to be empty you have a good case for throwing an exception instead of returning.

Comment: Either you're misremembering what the teacher said or he got it backwards - since `first` is returning a string auto will use string.

Comment: "When I asked my teacher how to_string goes because I didnt know what name of to_string was he said that I dont need it cause auto z = first(v) shouldnt be string." Sorry, I can't make sense of this sentence. I think you should talk to your teacher about this again.

Comment: Even though you can write a function that can return different types, this information needs to be available at compile time. This can only work, if the input is constexpr which afaik is not the case here. If you literally want to output the string `"No value!"` there doesn't seem to be a good way of achieving this short of overloading `operator<<`. Btw: an alternative to your code that would certainly make the professor unhappy: `char const* first(std::vector const& v) { return v.empty() ? "No Value!" : "3.14"; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have `first()` return a `std::optional<T>`, where if `ve` is empty then return `std::nullopt`, otherwise return `v.front()`.

And then overload `operator<<` to print the `std::optional<T>`.

For example:

```cpp
#include <optional>

template <typename T>
std::optional<T> first(const std::vector<T>& ve){
    if (ve.empty())
        return std::nullopt;
    else
        return ve.front();
}

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::optional<T>& op) {
    if (op.has_value())
        os << op.value();
    else
        os << "No value!";
    return os;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/67v5fqx35)

Comment: Note that declaring a global operator that doesn't depend on any of your own types is naughty. The standard doesn't promise that it won't introduce such operator in future, breaking your program.

Answer (score 2):

> Can one function have two different return types?

No.

However, function can return a sum type. A sum type is sort of a wrapper for more than one type. Standard library has for example `std::variant` that can wrap any type from a set. It's a tagged union. Another sum type that you may find useful is `std::optional` which can either contain a value of some type, or not.

Now, the standard character streams don't know how to print an optional, and defining an operator for that purpose would not be a good idea. So, if we have to have exactly the described behaviour for the exactly shown program, then we should define the sum type ourselves. It's still best to delegate to the standard library:

```
struct printable_optional {
    std::optional<double> opt;
    friend std::ostream&
    operator<<(std::ostream& os, const printable_optional& po) {
        if (po.opt) {
            os << po.opt.value();
        } else {
            os << "No value!";
        }
        return os;
    }
};

printable_optional
first(std::vector<double>& v)
{
    if (v.empty()) {
        return {std::nullopt};
    } else {
        return {v.front()};
    }
}
```

---

That said, the exercise is somewhat convoluted.